# Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a<b$ and $f(a)=f(b)=0$ with $f'(a)>0, f'(b)>0. $ Prove that $\exists c \in (a,b) $ such that $f(c) =0, f'(c)\leq0$

Tags: real-analysis

Preliminaries: $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ is differentiable;

Proved before that if $f'(p) > 0 \to \exists \delta > 0 : f(x)<f(p)<
f(y) \ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R} : p-\delta < x < p < y < p+ \delta$

I wonder if there is an easier and more direct proof that this:

I proved the first part using Rolle's Theorem:
for $f(a)=f(b), \exists p: f(p)=0$
for the second part of the proof, I let $C={p \in \mathbb{R} : f(p)=0} $

Then, $c=\min(P)$

Since $f$ is differentiable,
$\lim G_c(h) _{h \to 0} = \lim G_c(h) _ {h \uparrow 0} $ where
$G_c(h) = \frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}=\frac{f(c+h)}{h}$ and $h \in (-\delta,0) $

Claim: $\forall h, G_c(h) \leq 0$
Proof:

Want to show that $f(c+h) \geq 0 \because h < 0 $

Suppose not.
But $ \exists \delta_1 :$ for $ a+ \delta_1 < c, f(a+ \delta_1) > f(a)=0$ and thus by IVT, $\exists p' \in (a+\delta_1, c) : f(p')=0$ contradicting the minimality of $c$ as a root.
So $f(c+h) \geq 0$
Hence lim $G_c(h) _ {h \uparrow 0} \leq 0 $ i.e. $f'(c) \leq 0$.

Edit: $f'(c) \leq 0 $ copy-pasted the question wrongly, my bad.

Comment: The proposition you state in the title is quite simply false: take $f(x)=x(x^2-1)$ on $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from @ancientmathematician's answer, let me give one more counterexample: take $f = \sin$, $a = 0$, $b = 2\pi$.  Note that $f' = \cos$, so $f'(a) = f'(b) = 1 > 0$, $f(a) = f(b) = 0$, but $f$ (sine) and $f'$ (cosine) never vanishes at the same time due to the basic identity $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ for all real number $x$.